# Compare excel column from different files

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, conditional-formatting

want to compare two different excel files in a way that if column A (file 1) match column A (file 2) then check for differences between column B (file 1) and column B (file 2)

Answer (score 0):

*Write this Formula in **Sheet 1's C1** of **Workbook 2** & fill down.*

```
=IF([Workbook1.xlsm]Sheet1!$A1=$A1,IF([Workbook1.xlsm]Shee1!$B1<>$B1,"No Match","Matching"))
```

**Note:**

- Open `Workbook1` before you write this Formula in `Workbook2`.
- The other option is VBA (Macro) to compare two Workbooks for similar and duplicate data.